# Как изменять размер всех элементов в Swing?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

Допустим, у меня есть JFrame с 16 кнопками с картинками размером 100х100, которые я разместил в квадрат:

```
{  
   public static final int FIELD_SELL_SIZE = 100;
   private static JButton[][] button= new JButton[4][4];
   for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                button[j][i] = new JButton();
                button[j][i].setIcon(new ImageIcon("button.png"));
}

{ 
    public void init() {
        setLayout(null);
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                add(button[j][i]);
                button[j][i].setBounds(j * FIELD_SELL_SIZE, i * FIELD_SELL_SIZE, FIELD_SELL_SIZE, FIELD_SELL_SIZE);
            }
        }
        setSize(400, 400);
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Как сделать, чтобы если я изменял размер окна, то изменялись бы и размеры кнопок?

Comment: Учитывая, что вы не используете менеджер слоёв по какой-то причине, то вручную определять размер в зависимости от размера фрейма. Но более логично было бы воспользоваться менеджеров слоёв.

Comment: Если вы не хотите использовать менеджеры компоновки, то можно запомнить размер фрейма в переменных, а потом как нибудь вычислять размеры кнопок через математические операции